# FInd a second array with minimum absolute difference

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Given an array with positive integers (can contain duplicate elements), I want to find a second array with positive elements ( but no duplicates ) such that  absolute difference between adjacent of both the arrays is minimal , i.e. summation of `abs(a[i]-b[i])` is minimal.
Additionally elements in given array are <= size of array.

I have tried the greedy approach so far, but it fails. Here is my attempt.

```
for(long long i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
    cin >> given_array[i];
}

sort(given_array.begin(),given_array.end());

for(long long i=0 ; i<n ; ++i)
{
    for(long long j=0 ;  ; j++)
    {
        // visited array keeps track if I have already used a element in answer array
        if(given_array[i]-j>0 && !visited[given_array[i]-j]) 
        {
            visited[given_array[i]-j] = 1;
            answer.pb(v[i]-j);
            min_value += j;
            break;
        }
        if(!visited[given_array[i]+j]) 
        {
            visited[given_array[i]+j] = 1;
            answer.pb(v[i]+j);
            min_value += j;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Here `answer` is my resultant array and `min_value` is the minimum absolute difference.
How do I approach this?

Comment: *I have tried the greedy approach so far, but it fails* -- Which means that whatever you planned out on paper is not correct.  There is no need to write a program if your plan is flawed.  If you believe your plan is correct, then debug your code to see where the program diverges from your plan.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I have tried a few other things like sorting the given array according to frequency and some other stuff. Nothing works so far. I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I am trying it against an online judge. Although the outputs are hidden.

Comment: that doesnt answer my question. You need to understand that using an online judge to "test" your code does not help you a bit to debug the code. It is really important that you understand that. if you want to debug your code you need to run it in an environment controlled by you. You need to write your own tests and you need to be able to attach your debugger to step through your code. I am almost certain that if you do that you can find the problem in the code yourself.

Comment: @idclev463035818, I don't post here much, I will edit the post accordingly. Also about debugging, I am not getting what you are trying to get at but how can I debug my code , If I don't even how to approach the problem.

Comment: @idclev463035818, I use GDB paired with VSC for debugging.